# Get PHP associative array from MySQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, associative

Iam trying to place data from SQL into array and simultaneously make the same array associated with name of source columns.
This is function, what I got:

```
GetRowFromDb("`id`,`name`,`email`", " WHERE `id`='1'", "database1", "table1");

function GetRowFromDb ($column, $condition, $database, $table) { 
  $target="`$database`.`$table`";
  $query="SELECT $column FROM $target $condition";
  $indexedrow=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query));
  return $indexedrow; 
}
```

This gives me back indexed array. When I want to know email, I need to use index (number) for example $result[2].
But I want to make my array associative with name of source columns, like this

```
print $result[email] //should return email
```

Thanks for reply!
Marcel

Comment: Why too many down votes for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`.

```
GetRowFromDb("`id`,`name`,`email`", " WHERE `id`='1'", "database1", "table1");

function GetRowFromDb ($column, $condition, $database, $table) { 
  $target="`$database`.`$table`";
  $query="SELECT $column FROM $target $condition";
  $indexedrow=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
  return $indexedrow; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this line

```
 $indexedrow=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query));
```

to

```
 $indexedrow=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
```

mysql_fetch_row returns array with numbers as keys and mysql_fetch_assoc returns the field names as keys.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are helpful.  You can use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)